# How to delete an image from a folder in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to delete an image from data base as well as from a folder in PHP5, but I am unable to delete it. Here is my code:

```
 <?php

   $obj=new Crud("localhost","root","","3g");
   class Crud{
     public $mysqli;
     public $data;

     public function __construct($host,$username,$password,$db_name) {
       $this->mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);

       if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
         echo "Error: Could not connect to database.";
         exit;
       } /*else{
         echo"Your Database successfully connected";    
       }*/
     }

     public function __destruct() {
       $this->mysqli->close();  
     }

     public function read() {
       $query="SELECT * FROM fashion";
       $result= $this->mysqli->query($query);
       $num_result=$result->num_rows;

       if ($num_result>0) {
         while($rows=$result->fetch_assoc()){
           $this->data[]=$rows;
           //print_r($rows);
         }

         return $this->data;
       }
     }

     public function delete($id){
       $query="DELETE FROM fashion WHERE id='$id'";
       $result= $this->mysqli->query($query) or die(mysqli_connect_errno() . "Data cannot inserted");

       if ($result) {
         header('location:fashion.php');    
       }
     }
   }
 ?>
```

By using the above code, the record was deleted only from database, but the image remains in the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution you are looking for is the `unlink` function which does that - unlinks and deletes a file.

You need the name of the file and the path to the file from the PHP current working directory to make it work. Kamrans answer shows this.

So:

```
    public function delete($id){
            $query = "SELECT filepath FROM fashion WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1";
            $fileLocale = $this->mysqli->prepare($query);
            $fileLocale->bind_param("i",$id);
            $fileLocale->execute();

        $result =  $fileLocale->get_result(); 
$fileLocale->close();
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
        {
/***
* only 1 result is returned so easy to collect 
***/
            foreach ($row as $r)
            {
                $filepath = $r;
            }
        }
    unset($r,$row);       
    /*** 
    $filepath is now the string of the location of the file.
    ***/
        if (unlink($filepath)){
                   $query="DELETE FROM fashion WHERE id=? LIMIT 1";
                   $delete = $this->mysqli->prepare($query);
        $delete->bind_param("i",$id);
        $delete->execute();
        $affectedRows  = $delete->affected_rows;      
                   if ($affectedRows == 1) {
                     header('location:fashion.php');   
                die(); 
                   }
```

- when using `header` always place a `die` command after it.
- use `unlink` to delete a file, it will return TRUE on success.
- filepath is the column in your database that you store the file location.
- connect and use the database using OOP principles, use prepared statements rather than queries, there is FAR less risk to you or your code.
- Add `LIMIT` to your SQL statements so if there is an issue, it will not mess up your whole table, for example. A safety measure.

Answer (score 1):

To delete an image from your folder you have to use `unlink`

```
$file = "yourimage.jpg";
unlink($file);
```

if image is in any other directory you have to specify full directory Path like
 `$file = "www/images/yourimage.jpg";`

Comment: the file name is save in datadase i have done that before in php4 now i m working in php5 that code is not working in it

Comment: public function delete($id){
      
      
      
 $query="select * from fashion where id='$id'";
 
 $result= $this->mysqli->query($query);
  
  $num_result=$result->num_rows;
 
 @unlink('fashion/'.$num_result['file']);
 
      $query="DELETE FROM fashion WHERE id='$id'";
  
  $result= $this->mysqli->query($query) or die(mysqli_connect_errno()."Data cannot inserted");
  
  if($result){
   header('location:fashion.php'); 
  }
  
  
 }

Comment: you are using `$num_result=$result->num_rows;` this will return you number of rows in the query not the data or file name so change that to `$result->fetch_assoc()` than it will return you the data from db.

Comment: i have use that bofore but only record from database is delete only but image remain in the folder

Comment: public function delete($id){ 
   $query="select * from fashion where id='$id'";
   
 $result= $this->mysqli->query($query);
 
  $result->fetch_assoc();
  
   @unlink('fashion/'.$result['thumbnail_image;']); 
   
   $query="DELETE FROM fashion WHERE id='$id'"; 
   
   $result= $this->mysqli->query($query) or die(mysqli_connect_errno()."Data cannot inserted"); 
   
   if($result){ 
   header('location:fashion.php'); 
   }
    }  
      }

Comment: @SherazKhan please put your code into your original question with "edit" because reading code in the comments is extremely tedious and difficult. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Before you delete the database reference, use it to fill the file name, which is what I am assuming is stored in the database.  If $id is the file name, just add it into a system command to remove the file.  This assumes Linux.

```
 public function delete($id){

   exec('rm /path to file/' . $id);//delete the file via system command.

   $query="DELETE FROM fashion WHERE id='$id'";
   $result= $this->mysqli->query($query) or die(mysqli_connect_errno() . "Data cannot inserted");

   if ($result) {
     header('location:fashion.php'); 
     die();   
   }
 }
```

Comment: Or in your case, maybe `$filename` is the equivalent of `$id`, and you can place it in the top section of your delete() function.

Comment: You do not want to use `exec` commands here, this is dangerous overkill of functionality. Use the PHP `unlink` function to do this.

Comment: I am not asking this in a doubting manner, but a curious one.  How is it dangerous?  I've seen people claim this, but I'm thinking it might be a bogeyman that the hive-mind has created.  Unless you're talking about SQL injection, which is another problem completely.  How can exec() be exploited or be dangerous?

Comment: `exec` command is extremely powerful and to insert a variable (`$id`) into an exec command there is a higher risk, the thing is that if you're allowed to run an exec command in your PHP on your server, then if that exec command is compromised your server can have any number of horrible things happen to it. And it's overkill, the `exec` level of server power is not needed when the `unlink` command does that and JUST that, rather than possible compromise of wiping the server and emptying the whole system contents. etc.

Comment: With the existence of unlink() for this purpose, that does make sense to use.  Is exec() inherently a bad idea?  Can it just plain be hacked in ways other than variable injection?  Or are you just saying don't use a flamethrower when you need a lighter?

Comment: Well both, `exec` does what the word implies, in executes an external program which leaves the scope of PHP and enters the world of wider more varied server security. How much do you know about `exec`? if someone can get any sort of access to your PHP `exec` command they can compromise your login, add their own logins, and then very physically steal your server and all its contents from you. ***IF***